# C++ problem with push() and pop() methods for dynamic LinkedList using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, linked-list

First of all I want to create an dynamic LinkedList with Pointers without using STL. It is an exercise to understand how pointers work in C++.

My problem is that my `push()` method doesn't create a FifoElement like I would expect. When I runstart the program it shows me nothing after I use the `pop()` method. An example of my `main` is below.

To `push` new objects into the List I'm overloading the `<<operator` and to pop the first element from the list i'm overloading the `>>operator`

My two classes are `Fifo` and `FifoElement`

Fifo:

```
template <class T>
class Fifo
{
    public:
        Fifo();

        void push(const T&);
        T pop();

        Fifo& operator<<(const T&);
        Fifo& operator>>(T&);


    private:
        FifoElement<T> *top;
};
```

FifoElement:

```
template <class T>
class Fifo;

template<class T>
class FifoElement
{
    friend class Fifo<T>;

    public:
        FifoElement();

    private:
        T value;
        FifoElement<T> *next;
};
```

snippet of code for push method:

```
...
template <class T>
void Fifo<T>::push(const T& val){
    //creates new Element
    FifoElement<T> *newElem = new FifoElement<T>(); //<= I think my problem is here but I am not sure..

    //inserts new value into Element
    newElem->value = val;

    //If Fifo/List is empty: Element is top...
    if(top == nullptr){
        top = newElem; //...füge am Anfang ein
        return;
    }

    //or:
    //when List has elements go to the end and then insert element at the end
    FifoElement<T> *tmpElem = top;
    while(tmpElem->next != nullptr){
        tmpElem = tmpElem->next;
        cout << tmpElem << endl;
    }
    //set new Element as next of the last element in the list 
    tmpElem->next = newElem;
}

template <class T>
Fifo<T>& Fifo<T>::operator<<(const T& val){
    push(val);
    return *this;
}
...
```

and the pop() method part:

```
...
template <class T>
T Fifo<T>::pop(){
    //should read the first element of the list and delete it...
    FifoElement<T> *tmpElem = nullptr;
    FifoElement<T> *returnElem = nullptr;

    //if top is empty it means that the list is empty...
    if(top == nullptr){
        cout << "Liste ist leer!" << endl;
        returnElem = 0;
        return returnElem->value;
    }
    //the new element is the new top
    else if(top->next != nullptr){
        top = top->next;
        returnElem = tmpElem;
        //hier wird Element gelöscht!
        delete tmpElem;
        tmpElem = nullptr;
        //
        return returnElem->value;

    }

    //if only top exists then return it and delete it after that
    else{
        delete top;
        top = nullptr;
        returnElem = tmpElem;
        delete tmpElem;
        tmpElem = nullptr;
        return returnElem->value;
    }
}

template <class T>
Fifo<T>& Fifo<T>::operator>>(T& val){
    pop();
    return *this;
}
...
```

an example of my main would be like this:

```
    ...
    int main() {
    Fifo<string> test;
    string ex = "Hey stackoverflow whatsup? :)";
    string ex2 = "can anyone help me?";
    test << ex;
    test << ex2
    test.pop(); //output here should be: "Hey, stackoverflow whatsup? :)"
    test.pop(); //output here should be: "can anyone help me?"
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

I hope that I didn't forget anything. It would be nice if someone could help me out. I'm sitting on that program since 3 days :(

Comment: Your conclusions are off. Drop them, and [debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your `pop` method, paying close attention to the values of your local variables.

Comment: The pop method makes no sense at all. `returnElem` was never set to `top`, it's set to `tmpElem` and both are nullptr at that point. Then you're deleting `tmpElem` after setting `returnElem=tmpElem` which will also delete contents of `returnElem` given all you did was a shallow copy (just setting pointers).

Answer (score 2):

Your `pop` method was too complex and contained errors, especially with memory handling. Doing something like

```
returnElem = tmpElem;
delete tmpElem;
```

is wrong because `returnElem` just became a dangling pointer since you did not create a copy of the `FifoElement<T>` and both pointers are pointing to the same element. I've rewritten it as

```
template <class T>
T Fifo<T>::pop(){
    T value;
    if( top ){
        auto const old = top;
        top = top->next;
        value = old->value;  
        delete old;
    } else {
        cerr << "error - queue empty";
    }
    return value;
}
```

With that change your sample code works. I have not checked it for additional errors. See working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbe0d0c4d0b740f7)

Comment: He cannot use `STL` which I believe includes `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Yup, now it meets the requirements. The pop method the OP wrote gave me chuckles. It's the weirdest pop I've seen so far.

Comment: One little thing, maybe nitpicking, but `top = top.next;` should be enough, no? Given if `next == nullptr` it will automatically become `top = nullptr`.